# what is the difference between ['[a,a,a]','[b,b,b]'] and [[a,a,a],[b,b,b]] in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

In my program, when I debug my code, it seems somewhere in my code I generate

```
X1=['[a,a,a]','[b,b,b]']
```

and somewhere else I generate

```
X2=[[a,a,a],[b,b,b]]
```

and when I want to add this two lists and then use `numpy.array(X1+X2)` I get error. The problem is I don't know what is wrong with my code as I don't even know what is the difference between this two (i.e with quote and without quote). If I find the answer to this question then I can find my problem too.

Comment: `X1` is a list that has 2 strings in it.  `X2` is a list that has two more lists in it... At least, as far as we can tell... (You haven't really told us what `a` and `b` are ...)

Comment: Quotes are for making strings. That's basic Python syntax, and it's no different with numpy.

Comment: Have you tried printing `X1` and `X2`?   I use diagnostic prints all the time.  And for arrays I also check `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that I can turn '[a,a,a]' which is a string into [a,a,a] which is a list?

Comment: *In my program, when I debug my code, it seems somewhere in my code I generate `X1=['[a,a,a]','[b,b,b]'] `*  Well, perhaps you're doing something wrong, but since you've only shown your output and not the code that produces these outputs, it's difficult to assist...

Comment: I remember somewhere I saw that with a very simple python function we can turn '[a,a,a]' into a list [a,a,a] but I don't remember what was it. So, don't think about my program. Imagine my question is how to turn '[a,a,a]' into a [a,a,a]

Comment: I wonder if you are thinking of: `np.matrix('1,2;3,4')`, a short cut way of making a small matrix, modeled on MATLAB syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to riff off of @JoshuaWierenga's answer:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> X1=['[a,a,a]','[b,b,b]']
>>> X2=[[a,a,a],[b,b,b]]
>>> [eval(i) for i in X1] == X2
True
>>> [str(i) for i in X2] == X1
False
>>> [str(i) for i in X2]
['[1, 1, 1]', '[2, 2, 2]']
>>> a, b = 'a', 'b'
>>> X2=[[a,a,a],[b,b,b]]
>>> [str(i) for i in X2]
["['a', 'a', 'a']", "['b', 'b', 'b']"]
```

You can see that X1 can translate into X2, but it's a little trickier going the other direction.

Comment: The tricky way is `'['+','.join(map(lambda x: 'a' if x==a else '0', [a,a,a]))+']'`, which gives the output as `'[a,a,a]'`.

Answer (score 3):

X1 is a list that contains two strings

X2 is a list that contains two lists that each contain three variables.

About converting the strings to a list you would have to make an empty list and then remove the square brackets from the strings and then look for "," and add what was found before it to the list.

Comment: I remember somewhere I saw there was an easier way to do this but I can't remember what was it. Python might have something for this

Comment: Given that the strings in question have named variables, you'd need to use `eval` to perform the conversion, which is generally not a secure or stable way of writing code. The correct solution is not to generate these things as strings in the first place.